# How to throw exeption from some method using c#

Tags: c#, try-catch, throw

What are key words from throw exeption like this?

```
public void methodOne() throw SomeExeption {
     try{
         doSomething();
     catch(SomeExeption se) {
         throw se;
     }
}

public void startThere() {
   try{
       methodOne();
   catch(SomeExeption se) {
       Console.writeln("FAIL");
   }
}
```

I don't know, how to write it. I am getting syntax errors.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should see docs: [Creating and Throwing Exceptions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx)

Comment: The throw should be inside the body of the method.

Comment: Even aside from the glaring syntax error in the first method (C# doesn't use checked exceptions like Java), *both* of these are examples of how ***not*** to handle exceptions.  In both cases the code is ignoring useful exception information and artificially making it more difficult to correct the problem.